# How to check if a value is between two other values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range of two columns with values in it. On the first column these are start page values of articles (it's in a magazine) ; on the second column these are end page values of these articles. Something like this :

[image]

What is need to do is taking some value, for example '48', that I have as a variable in my Google Apps Script code, let's call it 'folio', and then check for each row of the range if this 'folio' value is superior than or equal to the value in the first column AND less than or equal to the value in the second column. And if this condition is true, then get the row to use it further in my code.

That means, in my example :

value in the first column <= 48 <= value in the second column

So I have to find the highlighted row in the image above, as 48 is between 46 and 49.

I found a way to do this with Gsheets lookup 2;1 formula, something like this :

```
=arrayformula(lookup(2;1/((D1>=$A$1:$A)*(D1<=$B$1:$B));$C$1:$C))
```

Which is working well (here it's returning value in C column, with folio value in D1 cell, but never mind). Now I'd just need to get the same in script. I guess I would need a for loop, but I am not really sure, and don't really know how to write this…

Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example script of how to find the row bracketed by the number value 48.  `Array.find()` returns the row that matches the criteria.  `Array.findIndex()` returns the row number.  My data set may not match yours exactly so the row number may be different.  But you get the idea.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let found = values.find( row => ( row[0] <= 48 ) && ( row[1] >= 48 ) );
    console.log(found);
    found = values.findIndex( row => ( row[0] <= 48 ) && ( row[1] >= 48 ) );
    console.log(found);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
8:12:09 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:12:10 AM  Info    [ 46, 49 ]
8:12:10 AM  Info    11
8:12:10 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: TheWizEd > Works perfectly. Thank you so much. I thought I would have needed some complex script, in fact not at all… so that's brilliant !

Comment: If this solve your problem please mark it as the answer so other can find a similar solution.